# Instamojo - How to control redirect page message

Tags: instamojo

I was trying to get the message about the payment status(successful, Failed, Cancelled) using this script.

```
$status = $_POST['status'];

if $status == "success" (
?> CONGRATS! <? AND SO ON
```

but i was not successful.
It is my first time with instamojo so i would kindly ask you guys to help me with it.

Thanks & Regards
Bhaamb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering you're using PHP then you should be using `$_GET` not `$_POST` to get the values of query arguments.

---

Currently we return two query arguments with the redirection URL: `payment_id` and `status`.

Here the `status` argument is only for backwards compatibility and you shouldn't rely on its value to mark the payment as successful because anyone can modify its value.

The correct way is to use the `payment_id` and query our API to get the [payment details.](https://www.instamojo.com/developers/rest/#toc-payments)

A sample response may look like:

```
{
    "payment": {
        "payment_id": "MOJO3815000J72853518",
        "quantity": 1,
        "status": "Credit",                <---- Payment status
        "link_slug": "hello-api-inr-link",
        "link_title": "Hello API INR Link",
        "buyer_name": "A Gehani",
        "buyer_phone": "+9100000000",
        "buyer_email": "akash@instamojo.com",
        "currency": "INR",
        "unit_price": "9.00",
        "amount": "9.00",
        "fees": "0.45",
        "shipping_address": null,
        "shipping_city": null,
        "shipping_state": null,
        "shipping_zip": null,
        "shipping_country": null,
        "discount_code": null,
        "discount_amount_off": null,
        "variants": [],
        "custom_fields": null,
        "affiliate_id": "hiway",
        "affiliate_commission": "3.00",
        "created_at": "2014-12-16T13:17:27.943Z"
    },
    "success": true
}
```

Here if the value of `payment` -> `status` is `"Credit"` then the payment was successful otherwise it was not.

Again if you're using PHP then you may want to use our API wrapper: [Get Details of a Payment using Payment ID](https://github.com/Instamojo/instamojo-php#get-details-of-a-payment-using-payment-id)

---

<sub>Note that the API also returns `"success": true`, but don't confuse it for actual payment status.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

check if the status in url exists

```
if(isset($_GET['status']))
   $status =$_GET['status'];
```

now check if the status is failure or succes

```
if($status != 'failure')
{
   "redirect to success url"
}
else{
   "redirect to failure url"
}
```

Comment: It's not recommended to rely on `status` query parameter: The `status` argument is only for backwards compatibility and you shouldn't rely on its value to mark the payment as successful because anyone can modify its value. If you someone is verifying and payment using this on their end then   it's not the right approach, query the API using `payment_id` and get the status from there.